# Choosing the right model for prediction

Tags: machine-learning

I am a beginner in machine learning and have learnt the fundamentals behind the models. After working with a few datasets I probably have a very basic/stupid question:

How does one choose what model will be the most appropriate after looking at the dataset. I am mostly talking about classification problems here (some models are SVM, KNN, etc). my assumption is that this has to be done during visualization of the data, but for a beginner like me what could be the best approach to go about this?

As of now, I am trying to fit various models after tuning the hyperparameters and then cross validating them and using the model with the best score. However, I dont think this is the right way to approach the problem, is it?

If there are any articles regarding this please post links.

Comment: Intuition and experience plays a big role. Check out this [sklearn image](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html).

Comment: @AshutoshMishra much appreash!

Comment: Indeed experience plays a big role but in the end of the day applied ML is a practical 'science'. The 'only' way to know for sure which model is better is to use cross-validation trying out various algorithms (and hyper-parameters).

Comment: @Stergios and with practise i assume you would know which algorithms would be the most suitable for the different situations.